# How to set up a cron job to delete old database records using cPanel?

Tags: database, cron, cpanel, sql-delete

I set up a CRM, and enabled logging in the CRM. The logs are stored in a specific database  called crm and a table called crm_logging. I want any records older than a certain date (say 7 days) to be deleted so that the logs table doesn't become too large.

I have no experience doing cron jobs before, and I'm wondering how I would go about setting up a cron job to do this using cPanel's built in Cron Jobs page?

I've read that it would look something like:

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [column] < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

But I'm not sure whether I need to include something like this before I put that bit of code in:

```
mysql -u <username> -p<password> -h <name-of-mysql-server> <databasename> -e "<YOUR-QUERY-HERE>"
```

Any help you could give is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u <username> -p<username_password> -h <name-of-mysql-server> <databasename> -e "<YOUR-QUERY-HERE>"
```

Replace correct:
 for user with permission to access to Host MySQL for his location
 password of this user

You see, ypou must use **-p** or **--password=**